# How i can used sed or grep with this

Tags: sed, newline

I have a text file with 20000 lines, some line content 1 symbol or 2 or 3 from this range:

```
[\x{0990}-\x{099D}]
```

I want to add new line \n after the last symbol in the line like:
Before:

```
Alpha beta @#$ gama
```

After:

```
Alpha beta @#$
gama
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters are `ঐ঑঒ওঔকখগঘঙচছজঝ`, you may explicitly use them in `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(ঐ|঑|঒|ও|ঔ|ক|খ|গ|ঘ|ঙ|চ|ছ|জ|ঝ){1,3}[[:space:]]*/&\n/g'
```

A full inplace command:

```
sed -i -E 's/(ঐ|঑|঒|ও|ঔ|ক|খ|গ|ঘ|ঙ|চ|ছ|জ|ঝ){1,3}[[:space:]]*/&\n/g' file; # GNU sed
sed -E -i '' 's/(ঐ|঑|঒|ও|ঔ|ক|খ|গ|ঘ|ঙ|চ|ছ|জ|ঝ){1,3}[[:space:]]*/&\n/g' file; # Free BSD sed
```

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/Tj7X2N).

Here,

- `(ঐ|঑|঒|ও|ঔ|ক|খ|গ|ঘ|ঙ|চ|ছ|জ|ঝ){1,3}` is a bracket expression matching required chars 1, 2 or 3 times
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0+ whitespaces.

The `&\n` replacement pattern inserts back the whole match and then adds a newline.

**Tip**: To trim the spaces after those chars, use

```
sed -E 's/((ঐ|঑|঒|ও|ঔ|ক|খ|গ|ঘ|ঙ|চ|ছ|জ|ঝ){1,3})[[:space:]]*/\1\n/g'
```

Comment: Thank you it's worked, please how i can convert symbol to unicode, like "a" to \04321.

Comment: @Tomatow I am using [this site](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) to quckly check such things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for string:

```
([!@#$%^&*()_+=~`-]{1,3})([^!@#$%^&*()_+=~`-]*)$
```

and replace with:

```
\1\n\2
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/5JxMAy/1/).

The list of symbols can be adjusted to your needs. I added most of the symbols on the keyboard, on the numerical keys.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
sed 's/[\x0990-\x099D]\{1,3\} /&\n/' file.txt
```

**explanation**

```
s                              # use substitution
/                              # separator
[\x0990-\x099D]\{1,3\}         # 1 to 3 symbols
/                              # separator
&\n                            # replace with symbols\n
/                              # separator
```